# How to build a Java Microservices architecture with MessagePack

Tags: java, microservices, msgpack

I've recently discovered MessagePack, which seems to be an interesting alternative to JSONs.
If I'd like to use it in a Java Microservices Architecture, how can I make microservices talk between each other? Currently, I'm using the following stack:

1. Spring Boot
2. Spring Cloud (+ Eureka, RabbitQM, Zuul)

What I've found is a [sort of converter](https://github.com/making/spring-mvc-msgpack-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/App.java) that was, actually, written for a monolithic application. But what about the communication between microservices, so, the stream of messages? How can I combinate MessagePack with the Microservices Architecture?

Comment: Not sure the Architecture would matter too much. I'd imagine you download a serializer for MessagePack in Java and include it in each Microservice or application you want to use it in.

Comment: @Nope but how do I fire the msgpack message to another microservice? Unfortunately the available adapters don't do that (as far as I've understood)